Interpolation: From age groups to specific age
I have a database contains 10 age groups ( [15;19], [20;24]... [+60) and number of individuals in every age group but it doesn't follow any distribution (once it decreases and other time it increases), and I want to find the number of individuals for each specific age ( 15, 16, 17, 18....), any help please?
I'm working on the chronic disease free life expectancy and I have other data about people who have chronic.d but age groups are not the same as in data of population of the study ( it's (6-16),(17-18),(19-29)...) and I want to calculate the prevalence rates of chronic.d
Exemple of my data:
Data <- data.frame(age_groups=c("[15-19]","[20-24]","[25-29]","[30-34]","[35-39]","[40-44]","[45-49]","[50-54]","[55-59]","+60"),
in2020=c(3027, 14435, 10002, 7755, 5306, 2351, 5290, 2892, 1775, 11435),
in2021=c(3609, 17845, 8668, 5426, 4435, 1950, 3758, 2559, 2171, 12848),
in2022=c(3470, 16548, 11466, 8890, 6083, 2695, 6065, 3315, 2034, 13109),
in2023=c(3609, 17210, 11925, 9246, 6326, 2803, 6307, 3448, 2116, 13634)

Hi Nour and welcome on CrossValidated. You say "I want to find the number of individuals for each specific age". Can you elaborate on why you want to do that? I ask because the problem you want to solve (if it's more than just "finding the number of individuals for each specific age") might have another solution than what you think.

HI J-J-J and thank you. I'm working on the chronic disease free life expectancy and I have other data about people who have chronic.d but age groups are not the same as in data of population of the study ( it's (6-16),(17-18),(19-29)...) and I want to calculate the prevalence rates of chronic.d

There are several demographic approaches that have been developed for interpolating age group data. See the graduate() function in the DemoTools R package for a good overview.

I'd suggest you to edit your question to mention all the information you just gave in your comment above, so more people will see it and possibly take it into account in their answers.

This is a great example of why age should not be categorized when publishing results.

You have no information whatsoever on how ages are distributed within ages groups. About all you can do is pick a reasonable-seeming distribution, and apply it to every age group. For example, it may be reasonable to assume that ages are uniformly distributed within each age group - if you have $N$ individuals in a group $X$ years wide, you'd expect $N/X$ individuals at each particular age (e.g. with 50 individuals who are 20-24, you'd expect 10 of each year).
Of course, how effective this is depends entirely on how well your arbitrary choice of distribution reflects reality. If this represents a survey of people with ages ending in "0", for example, it would be a very bad assumption to assume that ages are uniformly distributed. It also might not be a good assumption for extremes of age ranges, for example in the age group of 60-100 year-olds, you'd likely see more 60 year-olds than 100 year-olds. To combat this, you could weight age ranges by the demographics of the population you're analyzing, if known.
But in absence of implicit or explicit selection by age, the uniform distribution might work well enough.

Once you have added two numbers together to make a sum, there is no way to tell which two numbers were used to make that sum. However, you could try interpolation, which would be tedious to explain without having the software to do so. For example, let us show a dirty first attempt to reconstruct where the numbers came from for 2020 using the Mathematica language:
y = {3027, 14435, 10002, 7755, 5306, 2351, 5290, 2892, 1775};
x = {17, 22, 27, 32, 37, 42, 47, 52, 57};
f[x] = Transpose[Join[{x, y}]];
Interpolation[f[x]]
Plot[InterpolatingFunction[{{17, 57}}, {5, 3, 0, {9}, {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 Automatic, {}, {}, False}, {{17, 22, 27, 32, 37, 42, 47, 52, 57}}, \
 {{3027}, {14435}, {10002}, {7755}, {5306}, {2351}, {5290}, \
 {2892}, {1775}}, {Automatic}][\[FormalX]], {\[FormalX], 17, 57}];
Show[%, ListPlot[f[x], PlotStyle -> Red]]

Which yields,

Notice that the >60 y/o category was not included, and the interpolation only extends from age 17 to 57, because in the contrary case we would be extrapolating. To use this, you would solve the interpolating function for a specific age, like 18. y/o,
and it would then give an answer that suggests what a five year age group would contain centered on 18. years old. To find the rate for a single year centered on 18 years old you would then divide that number by 5, as follows (again in Mathematica)
Interpolation[f[x], 18.]/5

which yields 1488.24, now obviously there is no such thing as 0.24 of a person, and 1488.24 is a crude estimate, which is greater than an estimate of 605.4 or the expected number for 17 year olds. (The middle age of 15-19 y/o divided by 5.)
Note that the Interpolation function call has a default smoothing called "InterpolationOrder -> 3" where linear segment interpolation would be "-> 1." There are also methods options, for example, Hermite interpolation. For more information see Mathematica's Interpolation documentation.
Finally, notice that if someone answers truthfully that they are 17 y/o, that means that they have finished their 17$^\text{th}$ year following their birth, or on average are approximately 17.5 years old, such that although the interval around 17 y/o for single year might be thought to be between 16.5 to 17.5 y/o, because ages are truncated, an "interpolation" of 17 years age actually includes the interval between 17 and 18 years of age. This introduces a step function granularity to the data with barely two significant figures for age, which while not as severe as five year groupings illustrates that best practice would be to collect date of birth and time of study (date of data collection) and that the time of study planning and statistical thought should precede data collection.
It would be best to specify age in days at time of study. To use years between 1900 and 2100, divide age in days by 365.25. Beyond that, a correction using common years that do not fall on centuries divisible by 400 would be needed. For example, 2000 was a leap year, but 1900 and 2100 would not be.

I'm not sure this works so well. If you sum up the interpolated values for each year of age, you generally won't even get the total number of people in the age bracket. The bucket centered at 42, for example, hits a minimum value of 2351, but all the other points in that bucket are higher than that - the sum of each year 40-44, divided by 5, is greater than 2351. Similarly, this plot shows fewer than 14435 people who are 20-24. This interpolation doesn't even recover the original values you gave it, and can seemingly create or destroy data points that never existed in the first place.

@NuclearHoagie Of course it is only very approximate. The data has been destroyed by binning. Note the range is from 17-57 y/o, so some data has been dropped. Otherwise it isn't interpolation that is wanted. The probability of someone being exactly 17 y/o is zero, and yet the curve has a point at 17 y/o. To attempt to reconstruct the actual curve more information is needed, although one can use other algorithms, combined extrapolation/interpolation, multiple stage or multi-step data reconstruction, prior population age data, or best of all, the actual data without binning.

Totally agree that the problem is underspecified and that there are many solutions which would yield identical binning, and furthermore that there is no way to choose among solutions that give the same binning. The issue is that this method will typically produce a solution that isn't even among the universe of possible candidates - it usually yields a breakdown that we know definitely was not what was observed. There are many equally good solutions, but this usually won't yield any of them.
